# I try using the F3 key on Minecraft to look at coordinates but it's not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I use FN+F3 and F3 alone. FN+F3 turns my music volume up and F3 alone does nothing... Any answers?

Comment: Have you looked at your controls/hotkeys? Sometimes they can get changed without you noticing

Comment: Try using the F3 key outside of MineCraft for other functions. It's possible you have a broken F3 key and is worth testing.

Comment: Are you using the Java or the Bedrock (Xbox One, iOS, Android, PlayStation, Switch, etc.) Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Your controls might have been changed in the options -> controls. Check that menu

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you're using Minecraft Java Edition? You can't use F3 for coordinates in Bedrock. You can use "Activate Cheats" and "Enable Coordinates" though.

Comment: But they *are* using Java Edition. Look at the tags on this post!

Comment: True, but perhaps that was in error. I edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 This question was asked before [tag:minecraft] was renamed to [tag;minecraft-java-edition], so you can't assume that.